# 'UnsafePointer<Int8>' has no member 'toString'

Tags: swift, linux, gtk

I am trying to help bind Gtk to Swift using [SwiftGtk](https://github.com/TomasLinhart/SwiftGtk). However, while adding a class for HeaderBar I get the error:

```
/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Coding/Swift/SwiftGtk/.build/checkouts/SwiftGtk--2571330441700638662/Sources/HeaderBar.swift:15:63: error: value of type 'UnsafePointer<gchar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<Int8>') has no member 'toString'
        get { return gtk_header_bar_get_title(castedPointer())?.toString() }
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~
/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Coding/Swift/SwiftGtk/.build/checkouts/SwiftGtk--2571330441700638662/Sources/HeaderBar.swift:20:66: error: value of type 'UnsafePointer<gchar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<Int8>') has no member 'toString'
        get { return gtk_header_bar_get_subtitle(castedPointer())?.toString() }
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^ ~~~~~~~~
/home/luis/Dropbox/Documentos/Coding/Swift/SwiftGtk/.build/checkouts/SwiftGtk--2571330441700638662/Sources/HeaderBar.swift:41:75: error: value of type 'UnsafePointer<gchar>' (aka 'UnsafePointer<Int8>') has no member 'toString'
        get { return gtk_header_bar_get_decoration_layout(castedPointer())?.toString() }
```

What seems to be happening is that [Gtk.HeaderBar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html) get_title() method returns gchar, which is (I think) of type UnsafePointer, which is not being casted into string correctly in the code:

```
public var title: String? {
    get { return gtk_header_bar_get_title(castedPointer())?.toString() }
    set { gtk_header_bar_set_title(castedPointer(), newValue) }
}

public var subtitle: String? {
    get { return gtk_header_bar_get_subtitle(castedPointer())?.toString() }
    set { gtk_header_bar_set_subtitle(castedPointer(), newValue) }
}
```

- Which approach should I follow to cast it into String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of getting a `String` from `UnsafePointer<Int8>`.  Please see `String` documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string.  The complexity here is that the same string of characters has different byte sequence representations depending on the encoding used.  One way would be to use `init(cString:encoding:)`.  For example, if you know that the buffer pointed to by an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` variable `buf` is encoded as ASCII, you could get a string like this:

```
let s = String.init(cString: buf, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)
```